# scp not copying folder structure as expected

Tags: rsync, scp

I have a path which is:

```
/one/two/three/four/five
```

and I'd like to scp `four/five/`

recursively to another machine at the location:

```
/zero/
```

so that it appears like:

```
/zero/four/five
```

My current path is `/one/two/three` when I do:

```
scp -r four/five user@bla:/zero/
```

but on the destination machine it looks like:

```
/zero/five/
```

instead of:

```
/zero/four/five/
```

(if rsync is simpler, happy to use that).

Answer (score 3):

Local operations like `mv four/five /zero/` or `cp -r four/five /zero/` don't create `/zero/four/` and hardly anyone expects them to. For this reason what you call "not expected" is rather expected to me.

`tar` stores the supplied path (see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1554244/432690)). Make use of this fact.

```bsh
cd /one/two/three \
&& tar -cf - four/five | ssh user@bla '
   cd /zero && tar -xf -
'
```

Comment: But you can make `cp` do that with `--parents`.

Answer (score 0):

`scp` behaves the same as `mv` and `cp` here. Assuming `four` contains other directories besides `five` you can run

```
ssh user@bla 'mkdir -p /zero/four'
(cd four && scp -r five user@bla:/zero/four/)
```

to just copy `five`.

- `mkdir -p` avoids an error message if the directory already exists
- `(cd ... )` runs the line in a subshell so you don't need to `cd` out of `four` afterwards